# Oracle Pl/sql return one cursor from multiple queries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure, which returns a cursor.

The application passes a parameter to the procedure which determines how many ID`s should be fetched, so the procedure doesnt know a head of time that number.

foreach ID i need to fetch the top 3 records with that ID.
what I have tried is using:

```
select * from table_name where id in (List of ID`s);
```

That query works, but i cant get the top 3 of each ID. If i limit the result count, i will get the TOP results of the first ID.

I thought using For Loop, executing the query for each ID and append the results to the cursor, but as I understand it`s impossible.

Any Ideas ?

***More details***
Lets say I have 5 ID`s and each of them have inner Id`s so 
Id 1 has (1,2,3,4,5) Id 2 (1,2,3,4,5) Id 3 (12,14,15,16,22) Id 4 (2,3,5,7,9) Id 5 (4,7,8,9,10)
In this case, which is the case I am dealing with, I dont see how row number will help me.
I need the top 3 for each ID, in this case the cursor should have 15 results.

10x alot and have a good weekend ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you have some criterion for determining the top three?

Anyway, the way to achieve this end is with an analytic function.  Oracle offers three distinct functions: ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() and DENSE_RANK().  These offer three slightly different interpretations of TOP 3.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407).

Here is the basic idea, using ROW_NUMBER(), which will return exactly three rows for each ID.

```
open rc for 
    select * from (
        select t.*
               , row_number() over (partition by id order by whatever ) rn 
        from table_name t 
        where t.id in (List of ID`s)
     )
     where rn <= 3;
```

The `whatever` in the ROW_NUMBER() clause is the column you use to determine TOP-ness.

Comment: I have a way to determine the top 3 for each od the ID`s sepertaly.

Comment: @Udi l: That's what the `PARTITION BY id` portion of an analytic/ranking/windowing function does (in this case ROW_NUMBER).

Comment: You soloution works perfectly, It`s exactly what I needed. 10x alot.

Answer (score -2):

Another idea to go with would be to define an Oracle temporary table

```
create global temporary table temp_table_name
```

[Link to more information](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054)

Then in a for loop you can insert rows into the temp table for all of the needed ids. The cursor returned would then be the content of the temp table. Of course this solution only makes sense when it is not possible to get the result back from a single sql query

Comment: I want to emphasize that the preformance for this query is critical and shoud execute in the fastest way possible. 10x :)

Comment: Well it is perfectly possible to get the result back from a single query, so a global temporary table is an unnecessary overhead.